# Spark use reduceByKey on a nested Key-Value structure

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My data looks like:

> Customer1| item1:x1,x2,x3; item2:x1,x4,x5; item1:x1,x3,x6|time1|url
>    Customer1| item1:x1,x7,x3; item2:x1,x4,x5; item3:x5|time2|url2
>    Customer2| item1:x1,x7,x3; item3:x5|time3|url3

I want to ReduceByKey same customerIds and mapValues to get union of distinct items for each customerId:

> Customer1| item1:x1,x2,x3; item2:x1,x4,x5; item1:x1,x3,x6; item1:x1,x7,x3; item3:x5

This I am able to achieve by:

> val line = spark.sparkContext.textFile(args(0))
>     val record = line.map(l=>l.split("\|")).map(l=>(l(0),l(1))).reduceByKey((x,y) => x.union(y)).mapValues(x=>x.distinct)

Now, I want each item in the second column to be unique as well and all values in same key should be joined using union and distinct, to get something like:

> Customer1| item1:x1,x2,x3,x6,x7; item2:x1,x4,x5; item3:x5

once this is done I want to pick all frequency of each x, eg: x1:2, x2:1 ....
and updated a vector of x(1-10) for customerId with the frequencies I get.

Can this be achieved in spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do this in Spark! The way you have approached the problem has made it seem a bit more difficult that it actually is however.

So I can show a full copy-pastable to REPL example, let's assume your data is stored in a String (not args(0) file)

```
val data = """Customer1| item1:x1,x2,x3; item2:x1,x4,x5; item1:x1,x3,x6|time1|url
Customer1| item1:x1,x7,x3; item2:x1,x4,x5; item3:x5|time2|url2
Customer2| item1:x1,x7,x3; item3:x5|time3|url3"""
```

and the RDD you call "line" can be read into RDD "rdd" as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data.split("\n"))
```

So far nothing new. The next step is the important one. Instead of doing the counting and aggregating in layers, we can prepare our data to do it all in one go. This is much more readable, and also more efficient, since it is a single map followed by a single reduce.

```
val mapped= rdd.flatMap(line => {
   val arr = line.split("\\|")
   val customer = arr(0)
   val items = arr(1)
   val time = arr(2)
   val url = arr(3)

   items.split(";").flatMap(item => {
      val itemKey = item.split(":")(0)
      val itemValues = item.split(":")(1).split(",")

      itemValues.map(value => (customer, itemKey, value, time, url))
   })
})
```

We can see what's in this we can print it nicely with `mapped.toDF("customer", "itemId", "itemValue", "time", "url").show`

```
+---------+------+---------+-----+----+
| customer|itemId|itemValue| time| url|
+---------+------+---------+-----+----+
|Customer1| item1|       x1|time1| url|
|Customer1| item1|       x2|time1| url|
|Customer1| item1|       x3|time1| url|
|Customer1| item2|       x1|time1| url|
|Customer1| item2|       x4|time1| url|
|Customer1| item2|       x5|time1| url|
|Customer1| item1|       x1|time1| url|
|Customer1| item1|       x3|time1| url|
|Customer1| item1|       x6|time1| url|
|Customer1| item1|       x1|time2|url2|
|Customer1| item1|       x7|time2|url2|
|Customer1| item1|       x3|time2|url2|
|Customer1| item2|       x1|time2|url2|
|Customer1| item2|       x4|time2|url2|
|Customer1| item2|       x5|time2|url2|
|Customer1| item3|       x5|time2|url2|
|Customer2| item1|       x1|time3|url3|
|Customer2| item1|       x7|time3|url3|
|Customer2| item1|       x3|time3|url3|
|Customer2| item3|       x5|time3|url3|
+---------+------+---------+-----+----+
```

Finally, we can count and reduce into the vector you need:

```
val reduced = mapped.map{case (customer, itemKey, itemValue, time, url) => ((customer, itemKey, itemValue), 1)}.
   reduceByKey(_+_).
   map{case ((customer, itemKey, itemValue), count) => (customer, itemKey, itemValue, count)}
```

and view it: `reduced.toDF("customer", "itemKey", "itemValue", "count").show`

```
+---------+-------+---------+-----+                                             
| customer|itemKey|itemValue|count|
+---------+-------+---------+-----+
|Customer1|  item1|       x2|    1|
|Customer1|  item1|       x1|    3|
|Customer2|  item1|       x7|    1|
|Customer1|  item1|       x6|    1|
|Customer1|  item1|       x7|    1|
|Customer2|  item1|       x3|    1|
|Customer2|  item3|       x5|    1|
|Customer1|  item2|       x5|    2|
|Customer1|  item2|       x4|    2|
|Customer1|  item2|       x1|    2|
|Customer1|  item3|       x5|    1|
|Customer1|  item1|       x3|    3|
|Customer2|  item1|       x1|    1|
+---------+-------+---------+-----+
```

If you need everything grouped into an Array/Seq representation of a vector you can do this by further aggregating the data. Hope this helps!

Comment: There are also values for which time and url are not present, in this case arr(2) and arr(3) will fail with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. is it possible to filter the rows with 4 columns. Something like line.split("\\|")).filter(l=>l.length == 4) 
I can ignore the data without url and time.

Comment: Just remove those columns from the tuples then if they are not needed. Alternatively, `import scala.util.Try` and then update those lines to 
`val time = Try(Some(arr(2))).getOrElse(None)` and 
`val url = Try(Some(arr(3))).getOrElse(None)`

Comment: Depends on if you need the values in those rows or not. If you don't, then you can filter as you suggested. If you do though, then see previous comment :)

Comment: That works..thanks! :)
the reducer i need is `val reduced = mapped.map{case (customer, itemKey, itemValue, time, url) => ((customer, itemValue), 1)}.
   reduceByKey(_+_).
   map{case ((customer, itemValue), count) => (customer, itemValue, count)}`
About the last part.. how do i create a vector of itemValue count for each customerId. For egs. if header[x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9] 
customerId2: item_freq[0 1 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 0] according to values obtained against each x and 0 if not obtained
where